# How do I unserialize and then convert the resulting multidimensional array into plain text, stripped of code?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Thank you in advance of any help on this. I'm trying to export some product specs from a Wordpress site to a spreadsheet with WP All Export which allows the use of PHP filters, and we want it to export as easily readable text. The specifications live in a custom WP field which exports as a serialized array. I'm not at all well-versed in PHP, but I think I need to unserialize the WP field contents into an array and then I need to convert the resulting array into as close to a simple string as possible (although line breaks between spec categories would be ideal). Is this possible? Here is an example of one of the fields I need to convert:

---

a:3:{s:6:"header";b:0;s:7:"caption";b:0;s:4:"body";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:9:"Materials";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:26:"Steel alloy";}}i:1;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Weight";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:18:"2.25 lbs";}}i:2;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Length";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:16:"6.32 in";}}i:3;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:20:"Applicable Standards";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:46:"Meets OSHA xxx, ANSI xxx";}}}}

---

..to ideally look something like this:

---

Materials: Steel alloy,
Weight: 2.25 lbs,
Length: 6.32 in,
Applicable Standards: Meets OSHA xxx, ANSI xxx

---

Answer (score 1):

That serialized data has become malformed somehow. Several of the fields have an incorrect length e.g. Steel Alloy is 11 chars, but your string says 26. I suspect you have manually edited the data before posting. Here is the corrected version:

`a:3:{s:6:"header";b:0;s:7:"caption";b:0;s:4:"body";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:9:"Materials";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:11:"Steel alloy";}}i:1;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Weight";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:8:"2.25 lbs";}}i:2;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Length";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:7:"6.32 in";}}i:3;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:20:"Applicable Standards";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:24:"Meets OSHA xxx, ANSI xxx";}}}}`

Retrieving the data is fairly simple. You can tweak this to your exact needs:

```
$unserialized = unserialize($your_string);
foreach ($unserialized['body'] as $item) {
    echo $item[0]['c'] . ': ' . $item[1]['c'] . '<br />;
}
```

Output:

```
Materials: Steel alloy
Weight: 2.25 lbs
Length: 6.32 in
Applicable Standards: Meets OSHA xxx, ANSI xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like:

```
<?php
function parseCrazy($crazy){
  $o = new StdClass;
  if(preg_match_all('/(?<=")(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]).+(?=")/U', $crazy, $m)){
    $all = $m[0];
    for($i=0,$n=1,$l=count($all); $i<$l; $i+=2,$n+=2){
      $o->{$all[$i]} = $all[$n];
    }
  }
  return $o;
}
$crazy = 'a:3:{s:6:"header";b:0;s:7:"caption";b:0;s:4:"body";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:9:"Materials";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:26:"Steel alloy";}}i:1;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Weight";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:18:"2.25 lbs";}}i:2;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:6:"Length";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:16:"6.32 in";}}i:3;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:20:"Applicable Standards";}i:1;a:1:{s:1:"c";s:46:"Meets OSHA xxx, ANSI xxx";}}}}';
$o = parseCrazy($crazy); // access like $o->Materials, $o->Weight, $o->Length, $o->{'Applicable Standards'}
foreach($o as $k => $v){
  $a[] = $k.':'.$v;
}
echo join('<br />', $a);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. Both methods seem to work well, but not within the export process I'm working on. I may have to just deal with all the excess data :-/  Thanks again.